# How can I wire this replacement ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan, replacement

I'm trying to install a new ceiling fan with a remote. The old ceiling fan had this for wiring:

- black to green,
- red to white
- white to black & blue.

The new fan has black, white and green. The combinations I've tried have not produced any function at all. How should I connect the wires?

Comment: Where are you? (House wiring color conventions differ from country to country.) What do the instructions that came with the new fan say? Is there a ground wire you haven't told us about?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a switch in the room, and does the current ceiling fan have both a light and a fan?

The easiest way I've found to do this is to get a multimeter($5) and use it to determine which wire is hot (in the US, this is usually the black one).  The next challenge is to determine which wire (if any) is switched), and you do that by checking each wire with the switch on and off.

Chances are, your new ceiling fan has hot (black), neutral (white), and ground (green).
Typically, you would hook it up black -> black, white ->white, and green to either green or to a green grounding screw in the junction box, and you would cap (i.e. put a wire nut on) the switched wire.

Answer (score 0):

The green wire is likely to be the ground, but make sure that whatever happens, always make sure the wires are not live before handling them. The other two wires (black, white) do not really matter where they are hooked up to. So far for the wiring.

You mentioned it has a remote control. Are you sure that part works? Does it need batteries of some sort? Does the fan work at all?

You can check if the wires coming from the ceiling are OK by hooking up a simple lamp. The wires the lamp work on, will be the wires your fan should work on. The third wire will be ground.